# React + PHP API throws CORS preflight error

Tags: javascript, php, reactjs, cors, fetch-api

I am trying to call a PHP API running on `localhost:8000` from a React app running on `localhost:3000`. After many tries I am still getting the error:

> "*CORS Preflight Did Not Succeed*"

Sent from the React app:

[image: Sent from the app]

Sent from the devtools:

[image: Sent from the devtools]

My API has following headers:

```
if (@$_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']) {
  header("Origin: http://localhost:8000");
  header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
  header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS');
  header('Access-Control-Max-Age: 1000');
  header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept');
}
```

I call the API with fetch like this (but it somehow sends empty request body):

```
let inputData:object = {email, password}
fetch("http://localhost:8000/data/login", {
  method: "POST",
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
  },
  body: JSON.stringify(inputData)
})
.then(response => {
  console.log(response)
})
.catch(error => {
  console.log(error)
})
```

The strange thing is that the requests are working normally when sent directly from the browser devtools (2nd screenshot) or API clients like Insomnia:

[image: Sent from an API client]

Comment: Does `Access-Control-Allow-Headers:*` help?

Comment: @nice_dev Unfortunately not, I get the same error.

Comment: Ok, as mentioned in the answer, server has to respond with a 200 ok status for OPTIONS request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Problem

Your first screenshot indicates that the response to the preflight request has status code 404. However, a necessary condition for CORS preflight to succeed is an [*ok status*](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#ok-status) (i.e. a status in the range 2xx). See the [relevant section (3.2.3) of the Fetch standard](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#ref-for-ok-status):

> A successful HTTP response, i.e., one where the server developer intends to share it, to a CORS request can use any status, as long as it includes the headers stated above with values matching up with the request.
>
> A successful HTTP response to a CORS-preflight request is similar, except **it is restricted to an ok status, e.g., 200 or 204**.

(my emphasis)

### Solution

Make sure your server responds with a 2xx status to preflight requests that are meant to succeed.

---

### Additional remarks

1. Allowing the `Origin` header is never necessary, simply because it's set by the user agent. You can drop `Origin` from the value of the `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` response header.
2. Why you're setting an `Origin` header in the *response* is unclear... [`Origin` is a *request* header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Origin). You should be able to drop that `header("Origin: http://localhost:8000");` line.
3. Instead of "manually" implementing CORS (which is error-prone), you should consider using a proven CORS middleware.

Comment: Yes, this helped me solve it! Thank you very much. The problem was that I was returning 404 Request if `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] != "POST"`.

Comment: @DanielNýdrle Great, but consider using a reliable CORS middleware instead of manually setting CORS headers. You'll save yourself some headaches!

Answer (score 0):

Your cors origin must be localhost:3000.

header("Origin: http://localhost:3000");

Because your frontend running on 3000.

Where the request comes from should be added as cors definition.

Comment: Still the same result, unfortunately...

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are not outputting anything in `php` before returning the response to the frontend application. A simple `echo "test";` or a `print_r`, `vardump` etc. can trigger this error.

Also, make sure there are no empty lines before the opening `<?php` tags since they send a premature response to the frontend that may cause this error.