# Why am I getting a CORS error with jQuery but not with XMLHttpRequest?

Tags: javascript, ajax, cors, xmlhttprequest

We are facing weird issue while making a Cross domain API call from from UI code base where one way of Ajax request (vanilla JS) works however another doesn't (jQuery). Any pointer will help.

**Cross Domain Success call**

```
let url = 'https://somedomain.com/test-api/links';
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", url, true);
xhr.responseType = 'application/json';
xhr.onload = function () {
  // Successful request
  if (xhr.status == 200) {
    console.log('success')
  }
};
xhr.onerror = function () {
  // Crossdomain request denied
  if (xhr.status === 0) {
    console.log(xhr.response)
  }
};

xhr.crossDomain = true;
xhr.withCredentials = true;
xhr.send();
```

However with following code base (jQuery) we are getting error message stating -:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://sourcedomain.com/test-api/links'
> from origin 'https://callerDomain.com' has been blocked by CORS
> policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control
> check: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' header in
> the response is '' which must be 'true' when the request's credentials
> mode is 'include'. The credentials mode of requests initiated by the
> XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the withCredentials attribute

```
.ajax({
      url: "https://somedomain.com/test-api/links",
      method: 'GET',
      contentType: 'application/json',
      dataType: "json",
      crossDomain : true,
      xhrFields: {
        withCredentials: true
      }
    }).then((resp) => {
      console.log(resp)
    }).catch((err) => {
      console.log(err)
    });
```

**Apache Confirguration on sourcedomain.com**

```
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT"
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Credentials true
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "https://callerDomain.com"
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "*"
```

**Update:**
Since  below combination is invalida i updated apacahe configuration to

```
 Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "*"
 Header set Access-Control-Allow-Credentials true
```

**Apache updated Confirguration on sourcedomain.com**

```
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT"
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Credentials true
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "https://callerDomain.com"
//for testing only
Header set   Access-Control-Allow-Headers       "Accept, Accept-CH, Accept-Charset, Accept-Datetime, Accept-Encoding, Accept-Ext, Accept-Features, Accept-Language, Accept-Params, Accept-Ranges, Access-Control-Allow-Credentials, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Access-Control-Allow-Methods, Access-Control-Allow-Origin, Access-Control-Expose-Headers, Access-Control-Max-Age, Access-Control-Request-Headers, Access-Control-Request-Method, Age, Allow, Alternates, Authentication-Info, Authorization, C-Ext, C-Man, C-Opt, C-PEP, C-PEP-Info, CONNECT, Cache-Control, Compliance, Connection, Content-Base, Content-Disposition, Content-Encoding, Content-ID, Content-Language, Content-Length, Content-Location, Content-MD5, Content-Range, Content-Script-Type, Content-Security-Policy, Content-Style-Type, Content-Transfer-Encoding, Content-Type, Content-Version, Cookie, Cost, DAV, DELETE, DNT, DPR, Date, Default-Style, Delta-Base, Depth, Derived-From, Destination, Differential-ID, Digest, ETag, Expect, Expires, Ext, From, GET, GetProfile, HEAD, HTTP-date, Host, IM, If, If-Match, If-Modified-Since, If-None-Match, If-Range, If-Unmodified-Since, Keep-Alive, Label, Last-Event-ID, Last-Modified, Link, Location, Lock-Token, MIME-Version, Man, Max-Forwards, Media-Range, Message-ID, Meter, Negotiate, Non-Compliance, OPTION, OPTIONS, OWS, Opt, Optional, Ordering-Type, Origin, Overwrite, P3P, PEP, PICS-Label, POST, PUT, Pep-Info, Permanent, Position, Pragma, ProfileObject, Protocol, Protocol-Query, Protocol-Request, Proxy-Authenticate, Proxy-Authentication-Info, Proxy-Authorization, Proxy-Features, Proxy-Instruction, Public, RWS, Range, Referer, Refresh, Resolution-Hint, Resolver-Location, Retry-After, Safe, Sec-Websocket-Extensions, Sec-Websocket-Key, Sec-Websocket-Origin, Sec-Websocket-Protocol, Sec-Websocket-Version, Security-Scheme, Server, Set-Cookie, Set-Cookie2, SetProfile, SoapAction, Status, Status-URI, Strict-Transport-Security, SubOK, Subst, Surrogate-Capability, Surrogate-Control, TCN, TE, TRACE, Timeout, Title, Trailer, Transfer-Encoding, UA-Color, UA-Media, UA-Pixels, UA-Resolution, UA-Windowpixels, URI, Upgrade, User-Agent, Variant-Vary, Vary, Version, Via, Viewport-Width, WWW-Authenticate, Want-Digest, Warning, Width, X-Content-Duration, X-Content-Security-Policy, X-Content-Type-Options, X-CustomHeader, X-DNSPrefetch-Control, X-Forwarded-For, X-Forwarded-Port, X-Forwarded-Proto, X-Frame-Options, X-Modified, X-OTHER, X-PING, X-PINGOTHER, X-Powered-By, X-Requested-With"
```

**Response to the preflight request**
[image]

[image]

Comment: `Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *` and `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true` are [incompatible](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#credentialed_requests_and_wildcards).

Comment: @jub0bs Thanks for response however i am still wondering how it worked for Vanilla java script code

Comment: Can you show the relevant headers from the response to the preflight request as received by your browser?

Comment: That helps. The status of the response to the preflight request is 403, but for CORS preflight to be successful, it must be in the 2xx range; see [this other recent answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70497905/react-php-api-throws-cors-preflight-error/70498101#70498101) about that. You should fix that next. Be mindful that, because preflight requests never carry credentials, you shouldn't handle such request behind any authorisation middleware.

Comment: Thanks I am marking this as an answer . Thanks alot for your support

Comment: Cool. I've also completed my answer. 

Comment: @jub0bs one last query- bydefault browser not attching cross domain cookie (withCredentials: true) for POST PUT calls and thatswhy its showing 403 any pointer here please

Comment: Browser never attach cookies to preflight requests. See my [earlier comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70531105/why-am-i-getting-a-cors-error-with-jquery-but-not-with-xmlhttprequest?noredirect=1#comment124679879_70531105). Just a thought, but perhaps it would be easier for you to handle CORS, not at the Apache level, but at the application level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Problem(s)

#### The two requests are not equivalent

For the one sent via XHR, you're only setting the [content type of the *response*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/responseType):

```js
xhr.open("GET", url, true);
// ...
xhr.responseType = 'application/json';
```

However, for the request sent via jQuery, you're setting the [content type of the *request* itself](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) to `application/json`:

```js
.ajax({
  // ...
  method: 'GET',
  contentType: 'application/json',
  // ...
});
```

#### Use of the wildcard in conjunction with a credentialed request

A value of `application/json` for a request's content type makes it [*non-simple*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#simple_requests); as a result, a preflight request is triggered by your browser. However, you're responding to this preflight request with

```http
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
```

which is an [incompatible combination](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#credentialed_requests_and_wildcards). Therefore, CORS preflight fails, as explained in your browser's error message.

#### Invariably responding to preflight requests with a `403` status

Your latest edit shows that the status of the response to the preflight request is `403`. However, for CORS preflight to be successful, the status must be in the `2xx` range; see [this other recent answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70497905/react-php-api-throws-cors-preflight-error/70498101#70498101) about that.

### Solution(s)

1. Either don't specify the request's content-type to keep it [*simple*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#simple_requests), or (preferably) explicitly allow the `Content-Type` header in the `Access-Control-Allow-Headers` header rather than using the wildcard.
2. Make sure you respond with a `2xx` status to successful preflight requests. Be mindful that, because preflight requests never carry credentials, you should handle such requests in front of any authorisation middleware.